# Validation text not showing up. MDBInput Reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-redux, mdbootstrap

I am using Material design Bootstrap for my React project. I made a form, made input field using MDBInput. I am trying to use it's validation feature but I am not getting any message below it, when I leave the input field empty and click on the login button. I am getting red border though.
Here is the image, highlighting the place where text should appear.

[image]

Here are the codes:

```
     <MDBInput
            label="Email"
            type="email"
            value={email}
            name="email"
            onChange={onInputChange}
            required
            invalid= {MDBInput.invalid}
            validation= "Please provide your email"
          />
        </div>

        <div className="col-md-12">
          <MDBInput
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            value={password}
            name="password"
            onChange={onInputChange}
            required
            invalid= {MDBInput.invalid}
            validation= "Please provide your password"
          />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the error by downgrading the package to version `2.3.0` or `2.4.0`. I think it might have something to do with the breaking changes.
You can downgrade using this following command

```sh
npm install mdb-react-ui-kit@2.3.0
# or
npm install mdb-react-ui-kit@2.4.0
```